# Creating and populating reports through api

Tags: lightning, rest-api, api

Is it possible to create and populate a report using data that isn't in salesforce already? Like populating a table? Please give an example/source if you can.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, your question isn't very clear. Going in to more detail about what you're trying to do (and providing some detailed examples) and what you've researched/tried so far will probably help your question be better received. The bit about asking for "source" at the end of your question might rub some people the wrong way too (this site is more about helping you overcome specific problems, and less about giving you working code for free). You can [edit] your question to include additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, reports in Salesforce uses data that there is stored in the objects.

There are different ways to get external data, like an External Object.

You can see more about External Objects [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_define.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5).

Comment: Thank you that is very useful